# Requirements symfony bundle in AppKernel.php

Tags: php, symfony, bundles, liipimaginebundle

I created vendor bundle for symfony2

it has required bundle (such us liip/imagine-bundle).

in composer.php i insert necessary lines:

```
"require": {
    ...
    "liip/imagine-bundle": "1.3.0",
    ...
}
```

but i have error - **Bundle "LiipImagineBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file?**

i can add it in AppKernel.php, but i think it is not good practice.

**How i can use requirements bundles in my vendor bundle?**

Answer (score 0):

You do have to enable it in AppKernel::registerBundles method and it is considered as a right approach as mentioned here [How to Install 3rd Party Bundles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/installation.html)